# Get Discord Bot profile picture from ID

Tags: node.js, express, discord.js, ejs

How can I get the profile pic of a **BOT** using its ID,
its a website and I am using **ejs** so I can't use a function
`<img src=" https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/<%=bots[i].id%>/<%=bots[i].avatar%>.webp">`
i tried this and it doesn't work
I am using Discord.js in the back end

Comment: Although you included the tag I have to ask. Are you using discord.js? Also, can you add some relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, because you mentioned "bot" in bold, getting the avatar url of a bot is no different than the avatar url of a user. The problem with your code is that you used word "icon", when the correct route (from the [developer docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#image-formatting)) to get an avatar url is "avatars".

`https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/[user_id]/[user_avatar_hash].webp`